How to count observations after each filter in tidyverse R?
I often apply filters in R, e.g. when selecting a particular sample or feature or excluding implausible values. Is there a fast and easy way to keep track on how many units were deleted after every filter? I like to save the number of observations in a .csv or .txt file. I think Stata is reporting observations used after every step in a log file. What can I do in R?
data(mtcars)

library(tidyverse)

sample <- mtcars %>% # 32 obs
  filter(mpg > 20) %>%  # 14 obs
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%  # 11 obs
  filter(am == 0) # 3 obs


Maybe try a package like tidylog

You can use tidylog (a package built around the tidyverse) to add information in the console when you perform filter(s) and other tidyverse functions:
library(tidylog)
sample <- mtcars %>% # 32 obs
  filter(mpg > 20) %>%  # 14 obs
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%  # 11 obs
  filter(am == 0) # 3 obs

#filter: removed 18 rows (56%), 14 rows remaining
#filter: removed 3 rows (21%), 11 rows remaining
#filter: removed 8 rows (73%), 3 rows remaining


Very good, didn't know about this one. Can probably store consol to txt file with sink()?

We can use trace to write the log file.
trace(dplyr::filter, exit = quote(
  cat(format(match.call()), ";", nrow(returnValue()), "\n",
      file = "logfile.dat",
      append = TRUE)
))
if (file.exists("logfile.dat")) unlink("logfile.dat")

sample <- mtcars %>% # 32 obs
  filter(mpg > 20) %>%  # 14 obs
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%  # 11 obs
  filter(am == 0) # 3 obs

file.show("logfile.dat")


Nice demonstration of how to set up a log file easily. +1

You can add a column with the number of remaining rows after each filter. I am not sure if it is what you want to.
sample <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(mpg > 20) %>%
  mutate(obs_filt1 = n()) %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%  
  mutate(obs_filt2 = n()) %>%
  filter(am == 0) %>%
  mutate(obs_filt3 = n())


    > sample
               mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb obs_filt1 obs_filt2 obs_filt3
Merc 240D     24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2        14        11         3
Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2        14        11         3
Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1 97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1        14        11         3


one good way would be to use a less common pipe operator from magrittr called the tee pipe %T>%. It allows you to pass a function as a side effect and then continue on with your coding. Below the code will print the nrow as each time and then you can go on to filter your dataset, note the use of both the more common pipe and then the tee pipe.
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
myprint <- function(x){print(nrow(x))}

 sample <- mtcars %T>%
   myprint() %>% # 32 obs
  filter(mpg > 20) %T>%
   myprint() %>% # 14 obs
  filter(cyl == 4) %T>%
   myprint() %>% # 11 obs
  filter(am == 0) %T>%
   myprint()# 3 obs


Perhaps you are looking for something that follows these steps:
{
  rows <- nrow(mtcars)
  
  # filter data
  sample_df <- mtcars |> 
    filter(mpg > 20)
  
  print(sample_df)
  
  # find number of deleted observations
  sample_df <- mtcars |> 
    filter(mpg > 20) |> 
    nrow()
  
  deleted_obs <- rows - sample_df
  
  # print number of deleted observations
  print(paste("The number of deleted observations =", deleted_obs))
  
  # write number of deleted observations to text file
  write(as.character(deleted_obs),file = "deleted.txt",append = T)
}

What the code chunk does is to filter the data, then compute the number of rows in the filtered data, and then subtract that from the total number of rows in the original data in order to give you the number of deleted observations.
Finally, it writes that data to a .txt file, which updates any time you change the parameters and run the chunk.


Then tweak it, e.g.
my_dplyr_filter = \(.data, ...) {
  nx = nrow(.data)
  .data = dplyr::filter(.data, ...)
  ny = nrow(.data)
  print(sprintf("Rows reduced from %i to %i.", nx, ny))
  .data
}
my_dplyr_filter(mtcars, mpg > 20L) |> head()
#> [1] "Rows reduced from 32 to 14."
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2


You can create a function operator to handle this information display (or output to a file), which gives you a lot of flexibility. This also works with other functions easily (see mutate/slice example):
library(dplyr)

verbose <- function(f) {
  force(f)
  function(...) {
    dat <- f(...)
    cat("#", nrow(dat), "rows x", ncol(dat), "cols", "\n")
    return(dat)
  }
}

verbose_filter <- verbose(filter)
verbose_mutate <- verbose(mutate)
verbose_slice <- verbose(slice)

sample <- mtcars %>% 
  verbose_filter(mpg > 20) %>%  
  verbose_filter(cyl == 4) %>%  
  verbose_filter(am == 0) %>% 
  verbose_mutate(new_col = 1) %>%
  verbose_slice(1)
# 14 rows x 11 cols 
# 11 rows x 11 cols 
# 3 rows x 11 cols 
# 3 rows x 12 cols 
# 1 rows x 12 cols 

